# refactoring a class to be more efficient

Tags: java, performance, jvm

i'm trying to refactor a class that i guess has several memory and runtime inefficiencies and bugs.
can you help me with that or remark my assumptions?

(for example

1.
i understand that the tostring method can use stringBuilder instead of strings concatinations...

2.also i guess it's better to use hashtable instead of list in order to getch the results from m_strings in o(1) instead of o(n) (in remove_string_method)

can you help me in approving it more??
i'm also not sure regarding those casting...
thanks

```
public class SomeClass
{
  private Date m_time;
  private String m_name;
  private List<Long> m_numbers;
  private List<String> m_strings;

  public MyClass(Date time, String name, List<Long> numbers, List<String> strings) {
        m_time = time; m_name = name; m_numbers = numbers; m_strings = strings;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
     if (obj instanceof MyClass) {
        return m_name.equals(((MyClass)obj).m_name);
     }
     return false;
  }

public String toString() {
   String out = m_name;
   for (long item : m_numbers) { 
      out += " " + item;
   }
   return out;
}

public void removeString(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_strings.size(); i++) { 
      if (m_strings.get(i).equals(str)) {
        m_strings.remove(i);
      }
   }
}

public boolean containsNumber(long number) {
    for (long num : m_numbers) {
     if (num == number) {
       return true;
     }
    }
return false;
}

public boolean isHistoric() {
    return m_time.before(new Date());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [GhostCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56311090/2711488) that you shouldn’t prepend `m_` to your member variables.

But more important, you should stop reinventing the wheel.

Consider

```
public boolean containsNumber(long number) {
    return numbers.contains(number);
}
```

Then, with

```
public void removeString(String str) {
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) { 
      if(strings.get(i).equals(str)) {
        strings.remove(i);
      }
   }
}
```

there’s the problem that when you remove an element at index `i`, the subsequent indices shift by one, so you’d miss an occurrence following the just removed one. On the other hand, if you are thinking about using a `HashSet` instead, you might not want to support duplicate elements, in which case you can stop after the first occurrence. You get all for free when not implementing it yourself.

```
public void removeString(String str) {
    strings.remove(str);
}
```

will remove the first element (or only element if you don’t support duplicates)

```
public void removeString(String str) {
    strings.removeAll(Collections.singleton(str));
}
```

will remove all occurrences of `str` correctly.

Whether replacing a `List` with a `Set`, like `HashSet`, is possible depends on how you intend to use the data, as these collection types have different semantics. Since you are not using the data at all in the shown code, we can’t say anything in that regard.

When you implement an `equals` method, you should also have a consistent `hashCode` method

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 1+name.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
    return obj instanceof SomeClass && name.equals(((SomeClass)obj).name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with naming: avoid Hungarian notation, so throw away all the m_ prefixes!

And yes, when looking up contained elements is a frequent task, then you obviously use a Set implementation, like HashSet. That would help with both data sets, names *and* numbers!